# jQuery plugin event binding on dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a jQuery plugin which has similar functionality as following:

```
  <h1 id="t1">title 1</h1>
  <h1 id="t2">title 2</h2>
<script>
$.fn.extend({
  test: function(opts){
    var o = { text : 'hello '};
    o = $.extend( o, opts  );
    return this.each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $div = $('<div/>');
      $btn  = $('<button />').text(o.text);
      $btn.click(function(){
        $div.text(o.text);
      });
      $this.after($btn).after($div);
    });
  }
});

$('#t1').test({text:'hola '});
$('#t2').test({text:'nihao '});
</script>
```

in which I have created some elements (a button and a div) on the fly and added some event bindings. In the sample code I have more than one element that will use this plugin respectively. However I noticed when I trigger the event, my bound event also applies changes to the last div I have created in the plugin.

Where have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `var` in front of your `$div` and `$btn` and created global variables by accident.

Comment: Cant believe I missed this... thanks alot! The code worked as intended after adding var!